# Resolving a TextView with vertically ambiguous constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

The error message says that `height and vertical positions are ambiguous for "Picture Message Text View".`

And here are the constraints for the `pictureMessageTextView`:

[image]

Now, when I change the height the height constraint from `Height >= 100` to `Height = 100`, the error goes away. However, if I keep it the way it is now, the error remains. And the reason why I want my height constraint to be `Height >= 100` is so that it can increase in size depending on the size of the text inside the textView. Any suggestions to get rid of the error?

Comment: But I can't have height constraints on the labels because I need to them to increase depending on how long the label is. And when I set the height constraint, it doesn't allow the the label to grow?

Comment: Set Height to `= 100` , but its priority to 750 (= same as the default content compression resistance priority). This way, your Textview should resist getting smaller if the content it too large for a Height of 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ambiguity because you defined too many constraints.
The rule of thumb is to have both leading and trailing space contraints or one of them with a dynamic width(width>=100 for instance).
The same applies to vertical(top, bottom and dynamic height).
So when you have all of the three constriants defined for either vertical or horizontal space, you'll get an ambiguity problem.

If you use the center vertically or horizontally, you're simultaniously setting the leading and trailing(or top and bottom respectively) as equal to each other so adding dynamic width (or height) would cause ambiguity in a similar fashion

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamic height of `textView` then you should remove the `bottom-space constraint`. This should also fix the error you are getting. You are getting this error because the `textview'height`is less than 100 based on the `top-space` and `bottom-space` constraints.